# hover card not working for on the fly added data

Tags: jquery

hover card is working fine when i refresh a page. But when i add an html row 
using

```
   $('.addactanme').click( function(){
                var activityName = $('#activityName2').val();
                var listId = $('#listId').val();
                $.post(
                   "<?php echo SITE_URL?>ajax/activity/addActivity.php",
                   {name: activityName, listId: listId },
                   function(data) {
                       var returnValue = $.parseJSON(data);

                       $('#activityWhere').val(returnValue.id);
                       var activityText = "Activity " + activityName + " Created";
                       $('#activitySuccess').text(activityText);
                       $('#activitySuccess').fadeOut(5000);
                       //console.log($('#activityWhere').val());
                       $('#empty-active').empty();
                       $('#activties-added').append(returnValue.html);
                   }
             );
```

the above function, it's not working. Only for the html content that's added using

```
$('#activties-added').append(returnValue.html);
```

Please help.

Comment: no idea what you're asking, but i suppose it's possible you have random misspellings where you're not referencing the right element on the page

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be due to misspellings in the code you've posted, you could try using **.on**, like:

```
$('.addactanme').on('click', function(){
 ....
```

OR if previous versions of jquery then:

```
$('.addactanme').live('click', function(){
  .....
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi,Thanks a  lot for you reply.  $('.addactanme').click( function(){
 is working as the control is going and new row is getting inserted.